# The directory name of obj/Debug/android/src/{name space} is a MD5 hash?

Tags: android, xamarin

In Xamarin Android, I am working with a DialogPreference class and need to access the full path of the class from the XML. I was having a hard time doing it and checked the obj/Debug where I found this:

[image: obj/Debug]

The name of the namespace is "IntervalAndroid", and all the corrosponding files are placed in the directory with the hash name.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you have updated to Xamarin.Android 5.1, and that this md5 directory is a consequence of the breaking change in the "name mangling scheme for Android Callable Wrappers".

See also:

- The release notes: http://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_5/xamarin.android_5.1/#Breaking_Changes
- The "Android breaking changes" section of the release announcement on the forums http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/37277/stable-release-xamarin-android-5-1-0-breaking-changes-new-features-and-bug-fixes/p1

Comment: Hi, Brendan, thanks for helping out. I read the release notes, but I didn't catch that `Classes that are referenced by files in the "Resources/xml/" folder will currently all need [Register] attributes, even if the "XML element name" syntax is used. This inconsistency will be fixed in the upcoming service release.` I added RegisterAttribute (and Activity/Application) in order to use the name space. But I had to register all my classes. This seems to be a less than ideal solution? How is it intended to use customs views without the name space? Thank you

Comment: "How is it intended to use customs views without the name space?"

That probably warrants its own question on the Xamarin forums. It would be interesting to get a few examples of "how do I do this?" alongside the "here's the best way" answers for some different scenarios that use ACW names.

Note that you can do things like:

`intent.SetClassName(_context, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(ClassName)).Name)`

Also note:
"If you only use the 'XML element name' syntax in your AXML files, then you will not need to add [Register] attributes"

Comment: Also notice that the doc for the Register attribute clearly says that you're not supposed to use it: "The RegisterAttribute is used by the monodroid.exe tool to control Java proxy generation. Actual member values and semantics are subject to change with minimal notice; do not use this attribute."  So you'll need to use it, but you're not supposed to use it.