# Android Google Analytics Unable to instantiate receiver com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingReceiver

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, analytics

I'm working on **Xamarin** with **Google Analytics ( 29.0.0.2 )**, my **Minimum Android Version is 4.2** and **Target Android Version 5.0** the **Target Framework is 5.0**.

Everything works fine when i'm in Debug and when i distribute my release app on Dropbox and Airdroid, but, when i put my app on Google Play Console Beta, at first installation, Google Analytics Crash with this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/it.riciclario.app-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/it.riciclario.app-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2587)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:147)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1358)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5264)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:900)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:695)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/it.riciclario.app-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/it.riciclario.app-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2582)
    ... 9 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingReceiver
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

I can't understand where is the problem and i don't know what the hell it's append. When the App crash the first time, the second time everything works fine. I've this problem **ONLY ON GOOGLE PLAY STORE** not in debug, not with dropbox release or Airdroid installation.. No crash, no errors on my Android Monitor Tool.

Any idea? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am late to the party but have also seen a similar issue, you should check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29984842/the-directory-name-of-obj-debug-android-src-name-space-is-a-md5-hash

Answer (score 2):

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingReceiver"

The `CampaignTrackingReceiver` intent (with `com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER`) will be called when the app is installed from the Play Store.

Note: There are three different "class" locations for `CampaignTrackingReceiver` depending upon the version (v2/v3/v4) you are using. (Personally I am *only* using v4+ now due to various issues in earlier releases)

- Is your manifest correct? If you can live without the install referer tracking, remove the receiver from your app's manifest.
- Do you have Proguard enabled and not whitelisting `com.google.analytics.*` and thus are stripping the classes
- Do you have other Google Play Services installed? Game, Location, etc.. as there are naming conflicts between some of those and Analytics. V2 and V3 both have problems related to this and different packages. It was finally corrected in V4. Know fixes for V2 and V3 are to manually edit the Google `.jar`s (Google search is your friend for this...)

Comment: Thanks,  i just enabled ProGuard but the app still crash on startup. I'm using Google Play Services Map and Google Play Services Analytics. I can't remove INSTALL_REFERRER. So i thinks is a naming problem with V2 and V3.. Any suggets? My Manifest is correctly configured as the example into the Lib. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem, tried adding proguard rule and it didn't help.

regarding manifest file, I don't have the receiver for CampaignTrackingReceiver  in my manifest set. so that should not be a problem.

Comment: @Shaegorath Ask a new question with your setup and issue.